# Swig csclassmodifiers does not work on Module class for C functions

Tags: c#, c++, swig

I am trying to generate a C# SWIG wrapper around [TA-Lib](http://ta-lib.org), a popular open source Technical Indicator library.

The TA-Lib code is C-code (a collection of extern "C" functions) and as a result, Swig generates a class like this:

```
// where ModuleName is specified as %module "ModuleName"
// where SomeCFunc is an extern "C" function in the target C dll
public class ModuleName { 
    public void SomeCFunc(...)
}
```

However. I need to define my class ModuleName as public unsafe partial. In the past I've used [csclassmodifiers](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/CSharp.html#csharp_partial_classes) e.g.

```
%typemap(csclassmodifiers) ModuleName "public unsafe partial class"
```

This should generate the class as `public unsafe partial` but in this case it's not working as the class is generated off the module name - I'm not wrapping a C++ class per se.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

No sooner had I posted, I discovered how to do this (despite a day working on it!) [#RubberDuckCoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)

So the solution is to specify moduleclassmodifiers in your *.i Swig interface file

```
%pragma(csharp) moduleclassmodifiers="public unsafe partial class"
```

The output module class now generates as

```
// where ModuleName is specified as %module "ModuleName"
// where SomeCFunc is an extern "C" function in the target C dll
public unsafe partial class ModuleName { 
    public void SomeCFunc(...)
}
```